# Breakpoints are not working with current debug configuration in PhpStorm using WAMP, XDebug

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I've tried setting this up multiple times and I can never get the breakpoints to work. What else do I need to do to get this working in Windows 10?

My php.ini file:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = "889"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

Vhosts Config File:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName skeleton.dev
    ServerAlias skeleton.dev
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/s3
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/s3">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

Web Application settings in PhpStorm:

[image: PHP Storm Web Application Settings]

Full XDebug in PHPInfo:

[image: XDebug in PHPInfo]

When trying to test a breakpoint I set one in PhpStorm and click the Phone icon to start listening. When I load a page in Chrome that contains the code with a breakpoint it does nothing.

Comment: 1) Please show whole xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output as captured via browser. 2) I see that you are using custom xdebug port number (which is also lower than 1024). Have you set the same port in PhpStorm settings? 3) please collect xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log 4) *"When I load a page in Chrome that contains the code with a breakpoint it does nothing."* Do you use xdebug browser extension to control debugger session? if not -- how do you activate/deactivate it?

Comment: It's working now, thanks! The port didn't match and I didn't have the validation directory setup correctly (I'm not sure if that part mattered or not). Then I installed the plugin and it's working perfect. Thanks!